# Subspace of a $2 \times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Consider the set $W$ which consists of $2 \times 2$ matrices on the form

$$\begin{bmatrix}2a & b\\3a+b &  3b\end{bmatrix}$$

where each bracket represents a row. Is $W$ a subspace of $2×2$ matrices? Also what is the dimension of $W$?

Comment: You mean $2ab$ is the first row and $3a+3b^2$ is the second row? Please clarify more...

Comment: I have re-edited it please check the question again , sorry for that.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried, and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Okay thats better, now what have you tried? Do you know what condition $W$ must satisfy for it to be a subspace? What was exactly your problem while trying to prove the conditions of a subspace?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom we know that w to be a subspace it should have the zero vector and thats true if a and b =0 , and the addition of two matrices that belongs to w should results in another matrix that belong to w . I am trying to prove this point generically plus I don't know how to get the dimension of w .

Comment: @FareedAbiFarraj please see my above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed: $W $ is the set

$$\left\{a\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0\\3  &  0\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\ 1 &  3 \end{bmatrix},\enspace  a, b\in K \right\},$$
$K$ being the base field.

Comment: Thank you , but what is the dimension of w ?

Comment: Tou have the generators. Can you show they're linearly independent?